# android alarm clock adjust alarm volume

Tags: android, volume, clock, alarm

I am creating an Alarm Clock application. I list all the ringtones available (not only the standart alarm tones). When the user clicks a tone from a list, I play it using a MediaPlayer. During this, I would also like to be able to adjust the Alarm volume using the volume buttons (on the phone). But when I press these buttons, I adjust the Media volume, not the Alarm Volume.

Is there any way around this?

Here is the code I am using to display the tones

```
private void chooseTone(final ArrayList<String> tones, final ArrayList<String> paths) {
    //final String lastRingtone = tuneName.getText().toString();
    //int i = tones.indexOf(lastRingtone);
    int i ;
    try {
        i = paths.indexOf(crt.tune);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        i = -1;
    }
    final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Ringtone").
            setSingleChoiceItems(tones.toArray(new String[]{}), i, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int index) {
                    String currentPath = paths.get(index);
                    try {
                        if (mp != null)
                            mp.stop();
                        mp = new MediaPlayer();
                        mp.setDataSource(currentPath);
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.seekTo(0);
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    selectedRingtoneIndex = index;
                }
            }).create();

    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    tuneName.setText(tones.get(selectedRingtoneIndex));
                    //uri = Uri.parse(paths.get(selectedRingtoneIndex));
                    crt.tune = paths.get(selectedRingtoneIndex);
                    try {
                        mp.stop();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {}
                }
            });
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    try {
                        mp.stop();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {}
                }
            });
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Gabriel, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @sandis not really :(. I finally let it be and added an option to configure the alarm volume in settings. Wish I had been able to do it though

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is working fine until the user starts playing the ringtone. While the ringtone is playing, you can, however, only adjust the media volume. Is there a way to fix this? I think that there must be a way of telling the MediaPlayer to play the music as "alarm", and not as "media".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also set AudioStreamType for a media player.

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```